# creating a linked list 2d array class

Tags: java

One of my class project is created a linkedlist2d array clas and i think im on the right track as of now or have an idea of what to do but one of my problem is in this method i am trying to pass two integers. The first integer will be rows and the second int will be columns. let say i am passed (2,3) to this method that means I should have 6 new null nodes. I tried this method right here and it says, "cannot infer arguments". What does that mean exactly and how can I fix this. if this program work there should be 6 nodes:
newNodes[0,0], newNodes[0,1], newNodes[0,2]
newNodes[1,0], newNodes[1,1], newNodes[1,2]

```
public Array2D(int rows, int cols){
        this.rows=rows;
        this.cols=cols;
        Array2DNode<E> [][]newNodes = new Array2DNode<>();

        for (int countRows=0; countRows< rows; countRows++){
            newNodes[countRows][0] = new Array2DNode<>();
            for (int countCols=1; countCols < cols; countCols++){
                newNodes[countRows][countCols] = new Array2DNode<>();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add enough code to your question to have compilable example.

Comment: What is `E ` here ? `Array2DNode<E> [][]newNodes = new Array2DNode<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you defined your

```
Array2DNode<E> [][]newNodes = new Array2DNode<>();
```

As a Array2DNode Object, Which You havent provided the code to but id assume this shouldnt compile(I tested it with a random Java class and my compiler threw an error just to be sure)

Instead i would do it as follows

```
 Array2DNode<E>[][] newNodes = new Array2DNode<>()[rows][cols];
```

Then you should be fine, Besides you seem to start iterating from 1 in your second `for` statement, Instead remove the first:

```
newNodes[countRows][0] = new Array2DNode<>();
```

And instead just start your cols iterator from 0, Which would be a bit cleaner!